# Button Opens All Buttons

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I created a dropdown button but when I replicate this and use it multiple times it opens all of the buttons on the page. I thought wrapping the button in class="dropdown" was the way to make sure this doesn't happen.

Can someone please tell me what is wrong with this?

```
    <li class="text-middle">
          <div id="dropdown_m" class="dropdown">
            <button class="button button-sm button-secondary button-nina dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> Dropdown Items </button>
           <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Option 1</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Option 2</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Option 3</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Option 4</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Option 5</a>
                     </div>
                    </div>
                  </li>
```

Comment: Could you please provide enough code in order to reproduce your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Each `<div>` has to contain only one Dropdown. If you put them in one single `<div>` browsers will execute them all in that div. Try to create a div for each Dropdown.

Comment: Thanks for the response but this didn't work. Placing each button in its own <div> still opens both buttons when one is clicked.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).